# Is it legal in England to publicly proclaim that oneself “hate[s] the Jews”?

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales, is-x-legal, public-order

Most likely if anything this could be a public order offence (one would think none other than under  section 5), but I recently heard someone warned by police that they could be arrested for saying this even though it was said as a joke, but was this police man right that it could be a racially/religiously aggravated crime merely to (whether jokingly or not) simply declare one’s own sentiment? There seem to be possible article 9 implications as well.

Comment: In the British language, there is a huge difference between “Jews”, “the Jews” and “Jewish people”, same as between “the Blacks” and “a black person” or “black people”. And a joke is when everyone laughs.

Comment: @gnasher729 what your subjective opinion of what a joke is is entirely off topic, but I think few would dispute that a joke could amuse some people while offending others. Also your presumption is quite unfounded, besides being irrelevant to the law, as humour is most often heavily dependent on context (which you lack).

Comment: In any event, what, do you suppose, is the difference between “Jews” and “the Jews”? I would think that “hating Jews” is worse than “hating the Jews”?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a "racial hatred" so illegal to do.

While Jews are likely not a race, they are beyond doubt an ethnic group. [The Public Order Act 1986, §17](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1986/64/section/17/enacted) also covers ethnic groups. It is not specific to Jews, all groups are protected. Even citizenship is protected so where differences based on citizenship are applied, must be done without the hate.

The offense itself is defined in [Public Order Act 1986, §18](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1986/64/section/18). There is some defense but I do not see much how "I hate" may not be seen as "threatening, abusive or insulting".

Comment: Racial hatred is defined as a term in the linked section, but not an offence. The closest offences seem to be s18, though this would require abusive or threatening language to be used, or s29B, though this would require incitement, rather than mere profession, or racial hatred.

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely recall that “stirring racial hatred” is an offence but have not just been able to find it.

The closest [offences](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/racist-and-religious-hate-crime-prosecution-guidance) that I can find are s18 (threatening or abusive language to stir racial hatred), or s29B (use of words to stir up racial hatred).

Whether simply professing one’s own hatred qualifies as either seems at best debatable.